# In React.JS how does one set the readOnly property on a component that renders a field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React.JS provides a variety of mechanisms for implementing components - class-based, components via React.JS hooks, and one can also use [Styled-Components](https://styled-components.com/). In a web application some times one wants to set the `readOnly` property on an `input` HTML element. To do so via HTML one uses the `readOnly` property/attribute on the `input` HTML element. The confusing thing is that HTML property/attribute has no value:

```
<!-- Create a readOnly input field to display the username -->
<input id='username' name='username' value='fred.fish' readOnly />
```

In React.JS if one is using [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) when one defines a component, one can specify properties (`props`). The value of `props` are then specified using standard XML attribute/property syntax.

Here is an example of a React.JS Component:

```
const PageTitleHeading1 = (props) => {
    const {
        id,
        textLine1,
        textLine2,
        textLine3,
        showCompanyNameLogo
    } = props;

    if (id === undefined || id === null || id === '') {
        throw new Error('Bad call to BasePageTitleHeading1. id is required ' +
                        'and must not be undefined, null, or the empty string.');
    }

    const pageHeadingLine1 = (textLine1 !== undefined && textLine1 !== null &&  textLine1 !== '') ?
                             <PageHeadingLine1Style key='1' className='pageHeadingLine1Style'>{textLine1}</PageHeadingLine1Style> :
                             null;

    const pageHeadingLine2 = ((textLine2 !== undefined && textLine2 !== null &&  textLine2 !== '') || showCompanyNameLogo) ?
                             <PageHeadingLine2 key='2' className='PageHeadingLine2' showCompanNameLogo={showCompanyNameLogo ? true : false} text={(textLine2 !== undefined && textLine2 !== null) ? textLine2 : ''}/> :
                             null;

    const pageHeadingLine3 = (textLine3 !== undefined && textLine3 !== null &&  textLine3 !== '') ?
                             <PageHeadingLine3Style key='3' className='PageHeadingLine3Style'>{textLine3}</PageHeadingLine3Style> :
                             null;

    return (
        <PageHeading1 id={id} className={`pageHeading1 ${props.className}`}>
            {pageHeadingLine1}
            {pageHeadingLine2}
            {pageHeadingLine3}
        </PageHeading1>
    );
}
```

I can the use the component using standard JSX syntax specifying its properties using standard XML attributes/properties:

```
        <PageTitleHeading1
            id='change-your-password-page-title-heading'
            textLine1='Welcome to the'
            textLine2=' On-Demand Training Platform'
            textLine3='Please change your password'
            showCompanyNameLogo={true}
        />
```

So what if I want to render a React.JS component that is an `input` field and set the `readOnly` attribute/property? This is a little confusing because in HTML the `readOnly` attribute/property in an `input` field has no value `<input id='username' name='username' value='fred.fish' readOnly />` where in React.JS when one specifies properties/attributes to be used in a component, the properties/attributes have values. So how does one set the `readOnly` property on a React.JS component that renders an `input` HTML element/entity?

Here is an example of a component that renders an `input` field using [Styled-Components](https://styled-components.com/). How does one render a React.JS Component that has the ReadOnly property set on it?

```
const StyledInputField = styled.input`
    width: ${props.width ? props.width : '100%'};
    height: ${props.height ? props.height : '42px'};
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px';
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React.JS, if you are using JSX, then readOnly functions in a component as a boolean property.

Below is a styled component (See [Styled-Components](https://styled-components.com/))

```
const StyledInputField = styled.input`
    width: ${props.width ? props.width : '100%'};
    height: ${props.height ? props.height : '42px'};
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px';
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
`
```

You do not really have to know or understand Styled Components to understand this answer. Now suppose I want to set the `readOnly` attribute on a component that I create from my `StyledInputField` component declaration?

```
<StyledInputField type="text" readOnly={true} />
```

React.JS interprets ReadOnly as the ReadOnly attribute and interprets its having a truthy value as the given component should be rendered with the readOnly attribute set on it.

This will in effect give you the following:

CSS:

```
.styledInputField {
    width: ${props.width ? props.width : '100%'};
    height: ${props.height ? props.height : '42px'};
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px';
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="styledInputField" readOnly />
```

React.JS recognizes the `readOnly` property and handles it appropriately. One may also use a state value or a `prop`

Example - here I am using `props.isReadOnly` to set the readOnly attribute on `StyledInputField`:

```
<StyledInputField type="text" readOnly={props.isReadOnly} />
```

If `props.isReadOnly` is truthy, then the readOnly property will be set. If `props.isReadOnly` is falsy, it will not be set.

- [True and False vs. "Truthy" and "Falsey" (or "Falsy") in Ruby, Python, and JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362)
- [How to Set the readOnly TextBox in React.JS TextBox component](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/textbox/how-to/set-the-read-only-textbox/)

I originally posted this answer here [How to use  as readonly](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/543)
. I am sharing it here on StackExchange as I am sure other React.JS developers need to render readOnly `input` fields and may be struggling a little to figure out the syntax. I hope this helps.